# Power Bi, colums to rows

Tags: powerbi, transformation, dashboard, unpivot

I have this table :[image]
Date column contains each market date, there are different oil price columns, some columns to capture change in price from previous day, and some column capturing change in %.

I want something like this:
[image]
In above picture, 1st column is different types of oil brand, next is previous day date, and next we have price, change in price from prev day and % change.

Problem I am facing is the oil brand names are column itself, facing issue to get them into row.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Power Query Editor for this table, then select all the columns that contain oil brands, then right click and select "Unpivot columns", then Power BI will turn the data into the format that *might* work for you.
I can't really tell without having access to your data set, but you can give it a go and see if it helps you to prepare your dataset for your visualization.